# Does for each loop modify the array? I read that it doesn't. However my program is. Pls explain. I am Java beginner

Tags: java

Here is the code that I am testing. My string array a showing modified array elements as dogs, cats, turtles.

```java
String[] a = {"dog", "cat", "turtle"};
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(a));//line
int i1= 0;
for (String j : a) {
    a[i1]=j+"s";
    if (i1 < 2) {
        i1++;
    }
    System.out.println(i1);
    System.out.println(a[i1]);
}  
System.out.println();
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(a));//line
```

output

```
[dog, cat, turtle]
[dogs, cats, turtles]
```

Comment: I don't know what you read, but as you've shown, you can modify the contents of a `String` array, or any object array.  You can't change the length of an array without redefining the array and copying the contents to the new array.

Answer (score 1):

The for-loop on it's own isn't modifying anything just reading the Object, but you are modifying it with `a[i1]=j+"s";`. You can modify any public object anywhere in your code as long as you're in the correct scope and it isn't a final.

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying your own array by concatenating s to it.
Try doing this

```
String[] a = {"dog", "cat", "turtle"};
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(a));//line
int i1= 0;
for (String j : a) {
 a[i1]=j;
 if (i1 < 2) {
    i1++;
 }
System.out.println(i1);
System.out.println(a[i1]);
}  
System.out.println();
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(a));//line
```